# EF 4 STEs: Dynamically Serialize the ChangeTracker

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, serialization, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 STE's with the T4 templates. Depending on what service contract is called, we might want a simple POCO version of an entity and other times we would like a version of the same entity that supports the ChangeTracker.

For the POCO version, we'd like to avoid the extra xml nodes for the ChangeTracker in the serialized payload if possible.

Is there a way to dynamically turn off the serialization of the ChangeTracker on a per entity basis at run time?

The only other ways I can think to achieve this include:

(1) Create two EF models with different T4 templates. One T4 template would include the ChangeTracker, the other would omit it, i.e. an editable model and a read-only model.

(2) Using ISerializable. I could implement custom serialization for the entity and include or omit it dynamically.

(3) Use one EF model, map the ChangeTracker entity to a POCO using something like AutoMapper.

Has anyone else suppressed the ChangeTracker dynamically?

Thanks!